# How to receive and show cURL/API requests in C# with webRequest Class

Tags: c#, curl, webrequest

i have problems with my c# programm  to send or receive cURL requests to a online telephone system, i hope to get some help there :)

I send commands like this to the server:

```
curl https://api.placetel.de/api/test \
    -d 'api_key=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX'
```

the server send in XML back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <result>1</result>
  <result-code>success</result-code>
  <descr>test login successful v1.1</descr>
</hash>
```

i have try with the [WebRequest Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) (msdn)

there is a API [documentation](http://www.placetel.de/wiki/index.php/API_Dokumentation) from the telephone online system provider ,but only in german.

okay, the connection works with this:

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.placetel.de/api/test.xml");
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "-d 'api_key=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX'";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
```

to show me the "answer" from the server i try this:

```
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();              
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);                
            dataStream.Close();               
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
           Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

**now i get the error message at:**

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
**"Error System.Net.WebException in System.dll" Connection to server failed**

how can i fix this problem and show the "answer" from the server.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to use `HttpClient` rather than the much older `WebRequest` class. Also, please post your error message as text in the post body, not as a screenshot.

Comment: And have the error in English too, you will get a lot more help that way as people will be able to understand it.

Comment: "Error System.Net.WebException in System.dll" Connection to server failed

Comment: "Connection to server failed" isn't a .NET exception. Show the actual, full exception, the HTTP status code and the response body. Also, you don't need `-d` (which may very well be the cause of the exception, as the server returns an error status), that's the cURL command line option for "data".

Answer (score 0):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.placetel.de/api/test.xml");
            request.Method = "POST";
            string postData = "api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            textBox1.Text = (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);      
            //Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            textBox2.Text = (responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Works :) thanks